# PHP - Parameterise sql table query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the sql query i have, how it can be Parameterise ?

I want to parameterise "$productId" as its dynamically added.

```
$result = $app->getReadDb()->query("SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE row_id = '".$productId."' AND attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = 4)");
$productName = $result->fetchAll();
```

The "$app->getReadDb()" has below methods in it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => prepare
    [2] => beginTransaction
    [3] => commit
    [4] => rollBack
    [5] => inTransaction
    [6] => setAttribute
    [7] => exec
    [8] => query
    [9] => lastInsertId
    [10] => errorCode
    [11] => errorInfo
    [12] => getAttribute
    [13] => quote
    [14] => getAvailableDrivers
)
```

I am not sure how to parameterise above query, any thoughts how it can be done ?

I have tried

```
$result = $app->getReadDb()->query("SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE row_id = '".$productId."' AND attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = :attribute_name)");
        $productName = $app->getReadDb()->fetchAll($result, ['attribute_name' => 4]);
        print_r($productName); exit;
```

but its not working

Comment: Adminer is a tool not a database :)

Comment: You need to research the [PHP PDO extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or this [useful tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: Which parts are you wanting to parameterise? Are you just trying to do the `store_id` parameter properly, or are you talking about parameterising other parts of the query

Comment: I want to parameterise "$image_path & $currentSite" as they dynamically added.

Comment: Ok, then read the PDO Manual pages and the tutorial I suggested

Comment: ok let me check on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235177/discussion-between-newtophp-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: @RiggsFolly  not getting how it can be implemented with above mysql query.

Comment: Well without knowing what other methods might be available in `$app->getReadDb()` neither will any of us

Comment: ok let me check that

Comment: I have updated question & added methods available in $app->getReadDb();

Comment: Do you have a table that maps `product_id` to `product_name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the `parameterise` means.
if you mean concat $productId into sql instead of using php str concat,you can use PDO [PrepareStatement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) like this.

```php
$sql = "SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE row_id = :product_id 
        AND attribute_id = 
        (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = :attribute_name)"
$statement = $app->getReadDb()->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array(':product_id'=>$productId,':attribute_name'=>4));
$productName = statement->fetchAll();
print_r($productName); exit;
```

if you mean not all the time the $productId will exist,you need to change sql based on $productId,here is a typical solution

```php
$sql = "SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE 1=1";
if($productId){
    $sql .= " and row_id ='{$productId}'";
}
if($attributeName){
    $sql .= " and attribute_id = 
    (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = {$attributeName})";
}
$result = $app->getReadDb()->query($sql);
$productName = $result->fetchAll();
print_r($productName); exit;
```

Comment: how to paramterise IN (".$currentSite.",0) ?

Comment: yeah,it will ok.or you can use `if($currentSites){$sql .= " and store_id in ({implode($currentSites)})"}`

Comment: can you please explain how it helps ?
parameterise query